# How to encode characters with accents in PHP

Tags: php

My issue is so simple. I have to make some Get query to a web service, when I put a text data with some special characters `é or à` I get a `?` character instead of the originals. I've tried this two function `urlencode() / rawurlencode()`. The two of the them are not giving me what I want. My question is how can get a text like this to my query `3+rue+égbelle` and not `3+rue+?gbelle`.

That's all.

Comment: Are you posting special characters? This question needs a bit more context.

Comment: Yes, I'm posting special characters like é or à.

Comment: `urlencode` and `urldecode` are working for me. Without more context this is really hard to answer.

Comment: Do "decorated characters" get corrupted between client and server (in the address of the GET request)? Do they get corrupted between server and client (in the response)? `That's all.` Ha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `php.ini`, file encoding and header definitions.

For multibyte characters you should specify in `php.ini` the following:

```
default_charset = "UTF-8";
```

It will be the default character set that is used by many PHP functions.

The same value will be added to the `Content-Type` header if other is not specified by using [`header()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

In the file you should use:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```